# How to customize ion-tab tabtitle font?

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass

How to customize ion-tab tabtitle font ? 
For example

```
  <ion-tab  [root]="tab1Root"tabTitle="Home" tabIcon="home"></ion-tab>
```

how to customize font of "Home" here ?   i created scss file inside tabs folder but couldnt make it work.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the following to your `app.scss`:

```
.tab-button-text {
  font-family: fantasy;
}
```

You can always use chrome dev tools or safari dev tools to check which class you have to modifiy to change the style of a specific element.